# A distributional limit involving delta funciton

Tags: limits, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I asked Wolfram Alpha to solve

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\delta(x)}{x}
$$

And the answer is $0$, without further information. Shouldn't it be $\infty$?

Comment: What is your definition of limit?

Comment: This is for sure not a "distributional limit"

Comment: This is nonsense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\delta(x)=0$ for $x \not=0$ then this could lead to Wolfram Alpha saying $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\delta(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}0 = 0$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha may be wrong. How do you know this is the correct limit?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Which step do you think might not be legitimate?

Comment: What is wrong is the OP wondering what is $\lim_{x\to 0} \delta(x)/x$. By the way $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ is bit ambiguous on if $f(0)$ makes sense.

Comment: @reuns "$f(0)$ makes sense" might be disputed here if it involves division by $0$.

Comment: @Henry Do you understand that the Dirac Delta is not a function and that the written limit is nonsensical?  It's certainly not a distributional limit.

Comment: Maybe they meant $\delta(x)=0;x\ne0$ otherwise $\delta(0)=\infty$ like [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/03/)